# MDX dimension usage in CASE statment

Tags: mdx, olap-cube

I want to check the number of the month and according to that divide by a certain number. The problem is that this code always defaults to the `else` statement. Can anyone spot the issue? Thanks.

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[SBBD]
 AS case [Date].[Calendar Month Number Of Year]
         when 2 then [Measures].[SB]/28 
         when 4 then [Measures].[SB]/30 
         when 6 then [Measures].[SB]/30 
         when 9 then [Measures].[SB]/30 
         when 11 then [Measures].[SB]/30 
         else [Measures].[SB]/31
    end, 
FORMAT_STRING = "Standard", 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'LB';
```

Comment: yep - you are trying to compare a member type to a numeric type - they will never match

Answer (score 1):

Try just comparing to the member's value in the condition of the `CASE` statement. Currently you are comparing a member `[Date].[Calendar Month Number Of Year]` which is not seen as a numeric expression in `mdx`, and comparing it to a numeric expression (2, 4,...).

Maybe the following works better:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[SBBD]
 AS case [Date].[Calendar Month Number Of Year].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_VALUE
         when 2 then [Measures].[SB]/28 
         when 4 then [Measures].[SB]/30 
         when 6 then [Measures].[SB]/30 
         when 9 then [Measures].[SB]/30 
         when 11 then [Measures].[SB]/30 
         else [Measures].[SB]/31
    end, 
FORMAT_STRING = "Standard", 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'LB';
```

I'd be more tempted to initially create a measure `[Measures].[NumOfMonth]` and then feed that into the case (chances are splitting in two like this will be quicker):

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[NumOfMonth]
 AS [Date].[Calendar Month Number Of Year].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBER_VALUE, 
FORMAT_STRING = "Standard", 
VISIBLE = 0 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'LB';

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[SBBD]
 AS case [Measures].[NumOfMonth]
         when 2 then [Measures].[SB]/28 
         when 4 then [Measures].[SB]/30 
         when 6 then [Measures].[SB]/30 
         when 9 then [Measures].[SB]/30 
         when 11 then [Measures].[SB]/30 
         else [Measures].[SB]/31
    end, 
FORMAT_STRING = "Standard", 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'LB';
```

---

**OTHER SIDE OF THE COIN**

Rather than worrying about values you could compare members. The condition of the case should use the `currentmember` function, and the numbers replaced by members:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[SBBD]
 AS CASE [Date].[Calendar Month Number Of Year].CURRENTMEMBER
         WHEN [Date].[Calendar Month Number Of Year].[2] then [Measures].[SB]/28 
         WHEN [Date].[Calendar Month Number Of Year].[4] THEN [Measures].[SB]/30 
         WHEN [Date].[Calendar Month Number Of Year].[6] THEN [Measures].[SB]/30 
         WHEN [Date].[Calendar Month Number Of Year].[9] THEN [Measures].[SB]/30 
         WHEN [Date].[Calendar Month Number Of Year].[11] THEN [Measures].[SB]/30 
         ELSE[Measures].[SB]/31
    END, 
FORMAT_STRING = "Standard", 
VISIBLE = 1 ,  ASSOCIATED_MEASURE_GROUP = 'LB';
```

Comment: Could it be that there is no case statement in MDX?

Comment: @PaulKar. Do none of my scripts work? In terms of what does and doesn't exist within Microsoft's version of `MDX` just look in `MSDN`. Case definitely does exist - it is not a great function to use as it is slow, due to calculations not generally running in block-mode when using it; but sometimes it is the only choice.

Comment: It's really strange but nothing worked with case statement. I tried iif and the same logic worked. Spooky. I apologize for not picking your answer. It was very helpful and elaborative, thank you for that. I just thought that it would be fair to not pick it since I couldn't get case to work (for future people that will view this thread).

Comment: Unsure what is happening in your cube. Please see the examples here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144841.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 . My approach follows these examples.